# Working with time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, time

I have developed a C++ app to print `Hello` at 23:01:50

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    time_t start = time (&start);
    cout<<ctime(&start);
    while(1)
    {
        time (&start);
        if( ctime(&start) == "Fri Jan 18 23:01:50 2013\n" )
            cout << "Hello";
        Sleep(500);
        cout << ctime(&start);

    }
}
```

But output is:

```
Fri Jan 18 23:01:49 2013
Fri Jan 18 23:01:49 2013
Fri Jan 18 23:01:50 2013
Fri Jan 18 23:01:50 2013
Fri Jan 18 23:01:51 2013
Fri Jan 18 23:01:51 2013
```

Why `Hello` is not printed?

Thanks

Comment: No no no! You shouldn't compare date-time like this (even with strcmp). What if format of date-time is different than this? Eg. "January 18, 2013, 11:01:50 PM"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ the equals operator "==" does not work as you expect for char pointers (which is what you are using). It is comparing the pointers which are actually pointing to different places in memory. To compare the strings (which is not the best way to do this check BTW) you will need to use a string comparison function.

For example:

```
if (strcmp(ctime(&start), "Fri Jan 18 23:01:50 2013\n") == 0)
{
}
```

For more info see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: `In C++ the equals operator "==" does not work as you expect for strings.` Yes it does. However, it does not for `char` arrays.

Comment: In this case strcmp is safe, since ctime is guaranteed to be null terminated as is a constant string. Strncmp should be used in cases where the strings are dynamic (even if ctime is technically a dynamic string).

Answer (score 3):

Change `==` to `strcmp(ctime(...), "Fri Jan 18...") == 0` instead. You can't compare c-strings with `==` since it compares addresses and not values.

```
if( strcmp(ctime(&start), "Fri Jan 18 23:01:50 2013\n") == 0 )
```